# How to test awt.* with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, junit, awt

I have a class which produces screenshot:

```
@Component
public class ImagesHandlerImpl implements ImagesHandler {
    ....
    public boolean doScreen() throws IOException, AWTException {
        final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        ...
    }
}
```

My app created with `spring boot`, and I need test it. But I get `java.awt.HeadlessException`

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest(classes = ImagesHandlerImpl.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = App.class) 
public class ImagesHandlerImplTest { 
    ...
    @Test
    public void whenDoScreenThenFilenameLikeTemplate() throws IOException, AWTException {
        imagesHandler.doScreen();
        final String name = dir.listFiles()[0].getName();
        assertThat("SCREEN_0", is(name));
    }
}
```

I try to prevent HeadlessException:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class);
        builder.headless(false).run(args);
    }
}
```

I use spring-boot version 1.5.6.RELEASE.

But it didn't help. I get log:

> java.awt.HeadlessException    at
>   sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenSize(HeadlessToolkit.java:284)   at
>   org.robinhood.image.ImagesHandlerImpl.doScreen(ImagesHandlerImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   org.robinhood.image.ImagesHandlerImplTest.whenDoScreenThenCreatePrintScreen(ImagesHandlerImplTest.java:51)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Help me. How to fix this issue? 
Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spring test runner **does not** invoke the `main method` of `App class`.
And it will turn on [Headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) by default.

You can specify JVM argument `-Djava.awt.headless=false` for executing the test case.
Another solution is setting the property during bean initialization.

```
@Component
public class ImagesHandlerImpl implements ImagesHandler, InitializingBean {
  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
  }

  public boolean doScreen() throws Exception {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: it didn't help. I get same result. `SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class); builder.headless(true).run(args);`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
// overcome @SpringBootTest setup
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false")
```

before the `doScreen()` method invocation.